# two way ssl with axis2 results in read timed out

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, fiddler

I am trying to consume a web service which requires two way ssl authentication, and belongs to a company X. I have created a client in axis2 and configured it to support https (imported server cert into truststore, set keystore path .. etc.). I keept getting read timed out exception when I invoked it. I should mention that the handshake passes and there are no exceptions concerning certificates (I have dealt with them).

I did the following (separate and in combination):
- used rampart with axis2,
- tuned down the firewall on my computer,
- bypassed my company's firewall (got a separate adsl line from isp),
- logged a ticket at the company's X helpdesk for help but they said it was ok on their end.

All the above did not help, so I used Fiddler to monitor the network traffic and it turned out that it worked with specific configuration:
- rampart turned off,
- behind my computer's and company's firewalls,
- fiddler capture turned on (https traffic by fiddler's proxy).

When I turn the fiddler off and remove the proxy I still get the read timed out exception.

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Read timed out
        at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:197)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:404)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:231)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:443)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:406)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        ...
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
        at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
        at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:148)
        at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:775)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:786)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1251)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:884)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:78)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:106)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.readLine(HttpConnection.java:1116)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.readLine(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1413)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMethodBase.java:1973)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodBase.java:1735)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1098)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:621)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:193)
        ... 76 more
```

What could be the cause of it? Please help me solve this problem. Thank you.

[edit]

I forgot to mention that I have tried to set different timeout values and it did not help. value above 4 minutes results in

```
'java.net.SocketException: Connection reset'
```

Approach with Fiddler works even with the default timeout. I get the response immediately.

I have debugged the SSL connection and compared it against this example: [Debugging SSL/TLS Connections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html) and it seems that the initial handshake is ok and all certificates/keys are exchanged properly between the server and client. That's both with and without Fiddler so I do not know why I keep getting read timed out without Fiddler running.

Comment: What do you mean with "two way SSL authentication" - HTTPS client authentication with private key & certificate?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant.

Comment: How specifically did you configure Fiddler to send the client's certificate?

Comment: On the fist run Fiddler asked to put the certificate file in a specified location. After that it started to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We faced similar issue and we were getting Read Time Out while trying to invoke a secured webservice, after a long analysis we found out that there was a mismatch in the transport protocol version.
Web-service was servicing on http1.0 and we were invoking it using http1.1. We modified the protocol version in our client code which resolves this issue:

Below is the code to specify http version-1.0

```
options.setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.HTTP_PROTOCOL_VERSION,
      org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.HEADER_PROTOCOL_10);
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I added the protocol version and it works now.

Comment: Thank for the answer, very helpful

Comment: May be this solution not cover all scenarios, but for me it works: someServiceStub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(HTTPConstants.HTTP_PROTOCOL_VERSION, HTTPConstants.HEADER_PROTOCOL_10);

Answer (score 3):

"Read timed out" means that the server took too long to respond to the client's request, and the client gave up waiting. If the service operator thinks their service is operating properly, you may need to adjust your client so that it waits longer for the service response.

Unfortunately, there are three different ways to set timeouts for the client, and it's not really clear from the information on the Internet what exactly is controlled by each timeout. Look at these two pages:

- [How to configure Axis2's HTTP Transport Sender at Client Side?](http://wso2.com/library/209/)
- [HTTP Transport](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/http-transport.html#timeout_config)

The first page illustrates how to get the `ServiceClient` and its `Options`, and how to call `Options.setTimeOutInMilliSeconds()` to set a timeout. The [Axis2 docs](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/client/Options.html#getTimeOutInMilliSeconds%28%29) describe that as "the wait time after which a client times out in a blocking scenario", and I *think* that's the timeout that you want.

The second page illustrates how to set the `SO_TIMEOUT` and `CONNECTION_TIMEOUT` from `Options`. It's *possible* that `SO_TIMEOUT` is relevant here.

Comment: I forgot to write that I have tried different timeout values and it did not help. Value above 4 minutes resulted in java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Answer (score 0):

From the error below,

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)

...
```

Another possible solution is, importing the server certification to your trusted keystore.